# CSS Class to Hide/Show Specific Elements for DataTables Tabletools

Tags: css, datatables, tabletools

I am using DataTables TableTools to Print and Export a table

Tabletools plugin changes every other element to display:none except the table itself
I would like to find a way to tell it to hide or show certian elements when you select the print button.

I know you can show or hide by putting a display:block on an element.

What I am looking for is a class that I may put on an element that tells tabletools to hide elements that are children of forced visible elements

Comment: Can you give some sample output?

Comment: Or a example whet you want to hide (tfoot?)

Comment: I have a `<div style="display:block;">``<div style="display:block;"></div>``<div></div>``<div></div>``</div>`

Comment: What is happening is when Datatables Tabletools goes through and hides all elements other than the table it does not hide the two divs inside the container that have not been forced to show. I would like to hide those divs when a user selects the print button.